# Error al insertar datos con php y mysql

Tags: php, mysql, aplicación-web

Tengo el siguiente problema al intentar ingresar datos a mi bd estos son los códigos:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title> Creacion de Usuario Operador </title>
<link href="estilos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="group">
<form action="crear_operador.php" method="POST">
<h2><em>Registro de Usuario Operador</em></h2>  

  <label for="rut">RUT: </label>
  <input type="text" name="rut" class="form-input" required/>

  <label for="clave">Clave: </label>
  <input type="password" name="clave" class="form-input" required/>

  <label for="institucion_cod_institucion">Cod Institucion:</label>
  <input type="text" name="institucion_cod_institucion" class="form-     input" required/>

 <label for="nombre_operador">Nombre: </label>
 <input type="text" name="nombre_operador" class="form-input" required/>

  <label for="ape_mat_operador">Apellido Materno: </label>
  <input type="text" name="ape_mat_operador" class="form-input" required/>

  <label for="ape_pat_operador">Apellido Paterno: </label>
  <input type="text" name="ape_pat_operador" class="form-input" required/>

  <center> <input class="form-btn" name="submit" type="submit" value="Crear Usuario Operador" /></center>

  <li><a href="indexadmin.html">Inicio</a></li>
  </p>
  </form>

 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

y el código php seria:

```
    <?php
    mysqli_connect('localhost','root','') or die ("error al conectar" .                 mysql_error());
    mysqli_select_db('proyecto') or die ("error seleccionar db" .     mysqli_error());

     $rut = $_POST['rut'];
     $clave = $_POST['clave'];
     $institucion_cod_institucion = $_POST['institucion_cod_institucion'];
     echo $institucion_cod_institucion;
     $nombre_operador = $_POST['nombre_operador'];
     $ape_mat_operador = $_POST['ape_mat_operador'];
     $ape_pat_operador = $_POST['ape_pat_operador'];


     $insertar = "insert into operador values('$rut', '$clave', $institucion_cod_institucion','$nombre_operador','$ape_mat_operador',  '$ape_pat_operador')";

    $resultado =msql_query($con, $insertar)
    or die("error al insertar datos");
    echo "datos ingresados";
?>
```

gracias a su ayuda pude verificar los errores y solucionarlos asi que adjunto el codigo correcto por si alguien mas tiene el mismo problema para que pueda solucionarlo, muchisimas gracias a todos los que me ayudaron a solucionar mi problema

```
$con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pw, $db) or die("no se pudo conectar");

$rut = $_POST['rut'];
$clave = $_POST['clave'];
$institucion_cod_institucion = $_POST['institucion_cod_institucion'];
$nombre_operador = $_POST['nombre_operador'];
$ape_mat_operador = $_POST['ape_mat_operador'];
$ape_pat_operador = $_POST['ape_pat_operador'];

$insertar = "insert into operador (rut, clave, institucion_cod_institucion, nombre_operador, ape_mat_operador, ape_pat_operador) values
 ('$rut', '$clave', '$institucion_cod_institucion','$nombre_operador','$ape_mat_operador','$ape_pat_operador')";

$resultado =mysqli_query($con, $insertar) or die("error al insertar datos");
echo "datos ingresados";
?>
```

Comment: ¿Cómo está definido `$con`? ¿Qué errores te salen? Intenta proporcionar un [mcve]

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php 
$resultado = msql_query($con, $insertar);
```

Esa línea no parece correcta, pienso que debería ser `mysql_query`, no msql_query.

En el fragmento de código tampoco se ve dónde inicializas `$con` (donde  haces la conexión al mysql).

Answer (score 2):

La query de inserción no es correcta, asumiendo que conectas bien con base de datos (revisa la conexión) y que este puede ser el error. Falta una comilla aunque no incluyas los campos.

```
$insertar = "insert into operador (campo1, campo2, campo3, campo4, campo5, campo6) values ('".$rut."', '".$clave."', '".$institucion_cod_institucion."','".$nombre_operador."','".$ape_mat_operador."',  '".$ape_pat_operador."') ";
```

Answer (score 2):

Asegúrese de que la cadena de conexión este funcionando correctamente y corrija los errores que le han señalado. Tengo entendido que mysql ya es obsoleto, le recomiendo que trabaje con mysqli.

Answer (score 0):

Inicialmente revise si el nombre de los campos de su tabla operador son los mismos que tienes en el INSERT. Para mi la query de inserción que tiene es correcta agregándole la comilla que le falta antes de $institucion_cod_institucion, y si el campo rut es la llave primaria, pero si tiene un campo auto_increment como llave primaria debería ser así:

```js
$insertar = "insert into operador (rut, clave, institucion_cod_institucion, nombre_operador, ape_mat_operador, ape_pat_operador) values
  ('$rut', '$clave', '$institucion_cod_institucion','$nombre_operador','$ape_mat_operador','$ape_pat_operador')";
```